# Jhipster generator skip auth code at --skip-server

Tags: angularjs, angular, jhipster

Why when we generate project with '--skip-server'

> yo jhipster --skip-server

part of authentication is lost. (on AJS/A2).It's right?
Everytime i need to paste part code (AuthServerProvider on Angular or authExpiredInterceptor on AngularJS) for working home page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you did not specify which authentication type you want with `--auth` option.
See the [doc](https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#-tips) or run `jhipster client --help`.

So in your case, you should run: `jhipster client --auth=jwt` for JWT authentication or the one you want.

Comment: If I do with `--auth=oauth2 --db=no` ( `--db` is mandatory with `--auth` ) the OAuth 2.0 is neglected and JWT is used instead.