# jhipster --skip-server. Spring Security

Tags: jhipster

I want to do front project of Jhipster.

As I see in the documentation I have to execute the command:

```
jhipster --skip-server
```

By itself it is not worth and you have to put options.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720061/jhipster-generator-skip-auth-code-at-skip-server
```

I do not see the possible options for the "--auth" parameter, in my case for a back with Spring Security.(I only see examples for jwt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available auth types in JHipster as of v4.14.2 and v5 are `jwt`, `oauth2`, `session`, and specifically for microservices, `uaa`.  All of these use Spring Security on the backend.

`jwt` - JSON Web Tokens (JWT)

`session` - Session-based authentication

`oauth2` - OAuth2 and OpenID Connect

`uaa` - JHipster User Account and Authentication (UAA)

See the JHipster [Securing Your App documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/) for a full explanation of each type.